# Folder to subdomain when autoappending www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a `.htaccess`-file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.no [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.no/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which autoappend `www` in front of the URL if it's missing. In addition we have to expand our site to a mobile version that we'd like to call `m.mysite.no`.

How do you do this and make the mod_rewrite ignore the `www`-rule? Unfortunately, this site is live, so we can't do much testing and we have little experience on the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.no [NC]
```

To:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|m)\.mysite\.no [NC]
```